# Telerik MVC Kendo Grid prevent hidden columns from being queried and transmitted

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using ajax binding with theTelerik MVC Kendo Grid, along with entity framework.  We rely heavily on the .ToDatasource extension method.  Using the column picker, the user can easily show/hide columns.  The user can fine tune a grid (filters, sorting, grouping, visible columns, etc.), and then save it with a specific name.  With a flick of a dropdown, the grid will instantly transform into any of the saved states.

From what I can see, when the hidden property of a bound column is set to true, the .ToDatasource extension method will still fetch the column from the database, and still transmit the column to the client.  Then when the user adds a column to the grid with the column chooser, the column instantly appears populated with data.  The column is added without any call to the server because the data is already on the client side.

My problem is that many of the entities that we have defined could easily have several hundred properties.  The entities hookup to ERP systems, which already have data models that are completely out of our control.  For example, one ERP system has 313 columns in the customer table.  This means that if the user displays 13 columns, 96% of everything else queried from the DB, and transmitted to the client is a complete waste.

What would be the best approaches to:
1.  Prevent hidden columns from being pulled from the db.
2.  Prevent hidden columns from being transmitted to the client.